# is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Tags: c#-4.0

I attempted to search for a solution on google and on SO but was not able to resolve my issue.

My code is:

```
    try
    {
        objEmployerAuditReportData empAuditData = new objEmployerAuditReportData();
        IList<EmployerAuditReport> listAuditBatchList = empAuditData.GetAuditBatchList();

        foreach (var batchList in listAuditBatchList)
        {
            IList<EmployerAuditReport> listAuditBatchDetails = empAuditData.GetAuditBatchDetails(listAuditBatchList("form_request_id"));
        }

        string PDFexportFileName="";
        string PDFexportFilePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDFReportPath"];

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

error message:
**'listAuditBatchList' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'**

I know this seems very simple, but I can't figure it out. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
This turned out to be an application architecture related issue. The correct solution was:

```
empAuditData.GetAuditBatchDetails(batchList.<propertyname>)
```

and form_request_id had to be set as a property "set" and "get"

Comment: The message is caused by `listAuditBatchList("form_request_id")` but what exactly are you trying to do there. And in the for loop, you are just initialized the same reference variable over and over again which doesn't seem right.

Comment: No, one is BatchList and one is BatchDetails

Comment: During the first iteration, you assign `listAuditBatchDetails` something and then during the next iteration, you assign the same variable something else with dereferences the previously stored value without even using it. I think you want something like `List<EmployerAuditReport>` defined outside the loop and just add items to the list in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is where you "call" `listAuditBatchList` with parentheses and a string argument, `"form_request_id"`.

`listAuditBatchList` is a list of `EmployerAuditReport`, so there is no way to call it as a method, and no string keys if you meant `listAuditBatchList["form_request_id"]`.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried the square brackets, but was getting another error. I will try it again

Comment: @user788487 No, I'm saying that the square brackets won't work either, because on a list you can only use indexes (integers) in the square brackets. What are you trying to do with `"form_request_id"`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use squre brackets([form_request_id]) instead listAuditBatchList("form_request_id").Other wise it will method.